# Class voids into a Dictionary

Tags: c#

I want to insert all voids in a certain class to a Dictionary, and then make a command loader. The dictionary is of type `string, command`, where the string represents the requested command. So for example, if `string = "stackoverflow"`, then execute `void stackOverflow(parameter1, parameter2)`. How is this possible?

I tried using:

```
public Dictionary<string, Action> Commands = new Dictionary<string, Action>();
```

But I don't think that's the right way the to approach the problem. Please help.

Comment: You want to put Action delegates into that dictionary, right? Not voids.

Comment: Will all your actions have the same signature (same parameter types in the same order)?

Comment: @Rawling Doesn't really matter. You can always change somemethod(par1,par2) to () => somemethod(par1,par2). The latter will be an action even though it invokes a method taking parameters. The arguments are captured in the closure.

Comment: @Tormod Not if OP wants to specify the parameters at call-time, which from his other comments he apepars to want to do.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want something like this:

```
class Test
{
  private static void Stack(int n)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("stack " + n);
  }

  private static void Main(string[] arg)
  {
    Dictionary<string, Action<int>> dic = new Dictionary<string, Action<int>>();

    dic.Add("stack", (n) => Stack(n));

    dic["stack"](10);
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why people always prefer `() => Stack()` over `Stack`.

Comment: I wouldn't call it preference, it's just what comes to mind first when you're used to also doing things like `() => Stack("a", 3)`... Although you could call doing it deliberately for consistency a preference, too.

Comment: @Henrik Because in this way it could be `() => Stack(param1, param2)`... Clearly in the "pure" case of `() => Stack()`, `Stack` would be enough... But symmetry is something important.

Comment: @Serve I did what you suggested, however, if I have some functions with arguments - how can I do add the void to the dictionairy without an argument, and then when I access it through a KVP - enter the argument? Thanks.

Comment: @Serve Hmm, but what if not all voids require int as an argument? O:

Comment: it gets shady there. You could use Action<object> in the dictionary and then call dic.Add("", (n)=>Stack((string)n); you lose all type checking then though

Comment: @Serve Yeah I figured it's kind of tricky if they have diff arguments... wel thanks aynyway!

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
public Dictionary<string, Delegate> Commands = new Dictionary<string, Delegate>();
```

and then use the `DynamicInvoke()` method to call it.

like:

```
Delegate del = Commands["Help"];
del.DynamicInvoke(param1, param2);
```

I'll add that if you have to pass parameters, then normally you should know which parameters you have...

```
string cmd = "DoSomething";
Delegate del = Commands["DoSomething"];

if (cmd == "DoSomething")
{
    Action<int, int> doSomething = (Action<int, int>)del;
    doSomething(1, 2);
}
```

Comment: `DynamicInvoke` sounds reflectiony... although if he'll be putting in methods with different signatures, that may be unavoidable!

Comment: (Actually maybe not unavoidable, if you know you need to call it with a `string` and an `int` you can cast it to an `Action<string, int>` which I assume is faster than reflection.)

Comment: @xanatos How can I add them to the dictionairy?

Comment: Isn't `DynamicInvoke` slow when compared to `Invoke`?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel The `Invoke` method exists only with strongly typed delegates (like `Action`, `Action<int>`, ...) and normally it isn't used (if you have an `Action<int>` you can directly `myAction(5)` insteado of the *equivalent* `myAction.Invoke(5)`). `Delegate` (the generic `delegate`) doesn't have it.

Comment: @xanatos I know all the two points you just told, IMO better to use most derived delegates like `Action` instead of using it's base class